# C program to split pcap file

Tags: c, split, pcap

Can anyone help me with the C programming for splitting a network packet capture file (.pcap file) into smaller sized files (of same type or other). Though utilities like editcap or T-shark are already available for the job, I would really like to understand the coding behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You can open pcap file with [pcap_open_offline](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_open_offline.3pcap.html) and read individual packets with [pcap_next](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_next_ex.3pcap.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Tomasz. Can you also give me some idea on how a .pcap file can be split into overlapping time series. Can I use editcap/T-Shark for that??

Answer (score 0):

```
Winpcap offers wide range of solution to this problem

After reading ...in Test Packet Capture solution

for ( j=0; j<ulen; j++, pChar++ )
            {
                printf( "%c", isprint( (unsigned char)*pChar ) ? *pChar : '.' );                        
            }


                for ( j=0; j<ulen; j++)
                {   
                            fprintf(fp1, "%s", pChar); 
                            //fprintf(fp1, "%s", strtok(pChar,"MIND_ID"));  
                            fsize1 = ftell(fp1);

                            if (fsize1 > 665600) // close after 1MB 
                            {  fclose(fp1); 
                               printf("\n The size of given file 1 is : %d \n", fsize1);   
                               break;
                            }   

                }
```

use this code to store first and then split the given file into any number you want.

Answer (score 0):

for splitting a network packet capture file (.pcap file)  use  library [pcap_file_generator](https://github.com/wkoroy/pcap_file_generator)

Samle reading pcap file:

```
PCAPFILE  * pfr = lpcap_open("./pcaplibtestfile.pcap");
  pcap_hdr_t   phdr;
  if( lpcap_read_header( pfr, &phdr ))
  {
    int rese_rec_read = 0 ;
    pcaprec_hdr_and_data_t  p_rec_data;
    do{   
       rese_rec_read = lpcap_read_frame_record( pfr , &p_rec_data);
    }while(rese_rec_read>0);
```

sample writing to file:

```
 PCAPFILE * pfl = lpcap_create("./pcaplibtestfile.pcap");
  for( i=0;i< PKTS_COUNT;i++ )
  {
    /* TODO:  fill data   memcpy(eda.data , YOUR_DATA_BUF,SIZE_YOUR_DATA_BUF  );
       eda.len = SIZE_YOUR_DATA_BUF;
    */
   lpcap_write_data( pfl , &eda , i, 0 );
  }
  lpcap_close_file( pfl );
```